# Android Room - Can't locate already inserted object in DB

Tags: java, android, android-room

So I wrote method to check if item is already added in Room database:

```
if(!CheckifExisits(item)){
                            itemViewModel.addItem(item);
                        }else{
                            Log.e(TAG, "getPrice: Item Already Exists");
                            context.runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(context, "Item is already added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
                        }



private boolean CheckifExisits(Item itemOutSide){
    Exists = false;
    itemViewModel.getAllItem().observeForever(items -> {
        if (items != null) {
            for (Item item: items){
                if(item.getUrl().equals(itemOutSide.getUrl())&&item.getName().equals(itemOutSide.getName())){
                    Exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return Exists;
}
```

Now we I add the item for the first time nothing happens the item is added to the database normally, after I click the add button again the method works just fine and I get message saying the item is already in database, but when I close the app and reopen it, not only it can't detect the is already in the database but it re-adds as if's a new item even though the item is already in database!

How is that so? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is DB related.
Try to replace your code with this:

```
private boolean CheckifExisits(Item itemOutSide){
    Exists = false;
    itemViewModel.getAllItem().observeForever(items -> {
        if (items != null) {
            for (Item item: items){
                if(item.getUrl().compareTo(itemOutSide.getUrl()) == 0 && item.getName().compareTo(itemOutSide.getName()) == 0){
                    Exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return Exists;
}
```

Equals is used to compare objects and I think you want to compare the contents of the strings.
See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/object_equals.htm).